# delphi csv export query result to tedit or tmemo box

Tags: sql, csv, delphi

I would like to export a query result containing only one column , to a tedit or tmemo box. I'm successful exporting it to a csv .It's only one column containing weights ie.

50.32
50.23
52.53
46.23
35.63

I would like to export these weight side by side either into my tedit/tmemo box or csv

50.32 ,50.23 ,52.53 ,46.23 ,35.63

TIA

Comment: Sorry , the first row or number should be listed vertically

Comment: Well, you can [edit] your question to fix that

Comment: You just concatenate the values together in a string, then Memo.Text := ThatString

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be sth like this?

```
  qryGETWeight.Close;
  try
    qryGETWeight.Open;
    while not qryGETWeight.Eof do
    begin
      memoWeight.Lines.Add(qryGETWeight.FieldByName('WEIGHT').AsString); 
      qryGETWeight.Next;
    end;
  finally
    qryGETWeight.Close;
  end;
```

Comment: @skafinski he seems to want the values side by side on a single line, not on different lines.

Comment: It now runs through the code but still doesn't display the result in the memo box .It just iterates through the dbgrid

Comment: @JohanDantuma Well it should. You ofcourse need to replace memoWeight, qryGETWeight, 'WEIGHT' with names of your own componenet or rename rename your component to fit this scenario.
 If you done this and still doesn't work could you make update on your post and post your code.

Comment: @MarcGuillot I don't think so. I think 2nd line was writen like this in case of TEdit. Bellow his post said that 1st line should be vertically so if it wants it side by side TMemo and Lines.Add should do just good. But ofcourse i can be wrong.

Comment: Look like it runs through each line on the dbgrid but does add each record into the memo box and addends it

Comment: @JohanDantuma try to change from .AsFloat to .AsString

Comment: I've originally changed it to tmemo , asString and changed to query.prepared , but still no luck Here is my code  frmMain.query2.Close;
  try
  frmMain.query2.Prepared;
    while not frmMain.query2.Eof do
    begin
     memo1.Lines.Add(frmMain.Query2.FieldByName('mass').asString);
     frmMain.query2.Next;
    end;
  finally
  frmMain.query2.Close;
  end;

Comment: @JohanDantuma ok you are missing frmMain.query2.Open;    You could also remove .Prepare since you don't have parametrized query. I've updated my post.

Comment: Still not working . I've broken down the code into only : memo1.Lines.Append(frmMain.Query2.FieldByName('mass').asString);
     frmMain.query2.Next; .and it does show the current selected dbgrid row's info and when i click on the button to go to the next command it does to the next row and displays that .But what i want is to add each "mass" to the memo box

Comment: @JohanDantuma:"But what i want is to add each "mass" to the memo box "  Then, you need to explain **in your q** what exactly to mean by that.

Comment: @skafinski:  Next time, please test code code before posting it.  As written, it won't compile, because of the AsFloat.  Corrections should be in your answer, not in comments,

Comment: I have added it to my original post "I would like to export these weight side by side either into my tedit/tmemo box or csv"

Comment: @JohanDantuma:  your comment stressed "mass" which is nothing to do with side-by-side layout, and your comment to your q says "listed vertically", not side-by-side.

Comment: @MartynA corrected. Remove -1